# pytest test needs parametrization at collection phase and at setup time

Tags: parameterization, pytest

I have some tests which I'd like to parametrize using some arguments which need the parametrization to happen during collection phase and some which need it to happen at setup time.  I'm unable to use
metafunc.parametrize in a pytest_generate_test hook since I need some fixtures to have indirect=True to pass the argname as a request.param, but the other arguments need to have indirect=False.

Any ideas how to do this?

Here's an example of what my tests look like and what I want to do:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if metafunc.function.__name__ == 'test_example':
        argnames = []
        argvalues = []
        parameters = getattr(metafunc.function, 'paramlist', ())
        for p in parameters:
            if type(p) == list:
                argnames = tuple(['myfixture'] + p)
            else:
                argvalues.append = tuple(['std'] + p['argvalues'])
            argvalues.append = tuple(['pro'] + p['argvalues'])
        # I want to do the following, but it won't work since some of the
        # args need indirect set to true and some need indirect set to false.
        metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, indirect=True)
    elif 'myfixture' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # we have existing tests which use the fixture, but only with
standard
        metafunc.parametrize("myfixture", "std")
    else:
        # we have existing tests which use older style parametrization,
non-fixture
        for p in getattr(metafunc.function, 'paramlist', ()):
            metafunc.addcall(funcargs=p)


def params(decolist):
    def wrapper(function):
        function.paramlist = decolist
        return function
    return wrapper

@pytest.fixture
def myfixture(request):
    If request.param == 'std':
        myfix = SomeObject()
    elif request.param == 'pro':
        myfix = SomeOtherObject()
    def fin():
        myfix.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
    return myfix

@params([
    ['color', 'type'],
    { 'argvalues': [ 'blue', 'cat'] },
    { 'argvalues': ['pink', 'dog'] }
])
def test_example(myfixture, color, type):
    # this is the new test we want to add

def test_something(myfixture):
    # existing test which only uses std fixture

@params([
    {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2},
    {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5}
])
def test_old_style(arg1, arg2):
    # existing tests which don't use fixtures
```

Thanks for reading through this! I know it's rather long.

Answer (score 1):

per design all parametization happens at collection time

Comment: Good insight, do you happen to have any references handy that backs up this point more formally?